# Formal proof for what algorithm return

Tags: algorithm, fibonacci, proof

I need to formal proof that below algorithm return 1 for n = 1 and 0 in other cases.

```
function K( n: word): word;
begin
   if (n < 2) then K := n
   else K := K(n − 1) * K(n − 2);
end;
```

Anyone could help? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: I tried but i couldn't do this formal

Comment: I'll give it a try. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: I assume `n >= 0` is a precondition.

Comment: Yes, n:word means thath n must be greater or equals 0, Thank you

Comment: Do your own homework?

Comment: Not exactly. I have to show proof on lecture

Comment: You'll get much more out of this if you show what you've tried yourself first. Much easier to help you get through it then.

Comment: I think you can use induction to proof this, recursion is perfect for induction.

Comment: I've tried induction and i got sth like this:
K(n) = K(n-1) * K(n-2) = K(n-2) * K(n-3) * K (n-3) * K(n-4) = K(n-3) * K(n-4) * K(n-4) * K(n-5) * K(n-4) * K(n-5) * K(n-5) * K(n-6) 

And now I dont know how to proof that this will end up on K(0)

Comment: You shouldnt go till 0. You are manually proove the formula for 0,1,2 , assume that it is correct for n and should proove for n+1

Comment: @leskukie, it's a good start to try to unravel the algorithm, but as you've discovered, it doesn't lead to any conclusion. It can be solved by induction. The straight forward approach is to use n<2 as base case (since that's the base case of your recursive algorithm). See my answer for details. I'm happy to answer follow-up questions if there's something that is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be proven by induction, but as previous posters have shown, it's tricky to get formally correct when referring to `K` directly in the proof.

Here's my suggestion: Let *P*(*n*) be the property we want to show:

*P*(*n*)    holds iff    *K*(*n*) yields 1 for *n* = 1, and 0 for *n* ≠ 1.

Now we can clearly express what we want to show: Ɐ*n*.*P*(*n*)

1. **Base case:** *n* ≤ 2

   Trivial check by case analysis:

   *P*(0) is ok, since *K*(0) = 0
   *P*(1) is ok, since *K*(1) = 1
2. **Induction hypothesis:**

   *P*(*n*) holds for all 2 ≤ *n* < *c*.
3. **Inductive step:** Show that *P*(*c*) holds

   1. By definition of *K* we have *K*(*c*) = *K*(*c*-1) × *K*(*c*-2)
   2. By the induction hypothesis, we know that *P*(*c*-1) and *P*(*c*-2) hold.
   3. Since at most one of *K*(*c*-1) and *K*(*c*-2) can be 1 (and the other must be 0) the product is 0.
   4. Which means that *P*(*c*) holds

Qed.

Answer (score 0):

For `n=1` by invoking the algorithm the answer is `K=n=1`, so we're done with that case.

For `n=0`, by definition, `K(0) = 0`.

For the case where `n>1`, we can solve it by induction:

**Base**: for `n=2`, we get: `K(2) = K(1)*K(0) = 1*0 = 0`

For `n=3`, we get: `K(3) = K(2)*K(1) = 0*1 = 0` Note that `K(2)=0` because we just showed it one line up.

**Claim**: For any `1<k<n`, we get `K(k) = 0`

**Proof** for any n>3: `K(n) = K(n-1)*K(n-2) =(1) 0*0 = 0`

---

(1): Induction hypothesis, and since K(n-1),K(n-2) are both apply for it, since n-1,n-2>1

---

P.S. Note that the claim is true for non-negative numbers, for example, if you allow `n=-5`, you get `K(-5)=-5` - which is a counter example to the claim.

Comment: What exactly is the induction hypothesis?

Comment: @aioobe `For any 1<k<n, we get K(k) = 0 `

Comment: You just prooved that fibonacci is 0 if n > 2?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri This is not fibonacci, fibonacci is `f(n-1) + f(n-2)`, not `f(n-1)*f(n-2)`, and has different base clause. Did you read the question/answer/definition of fibonacci?

Comment: Oops sorry, didnt notice that, looked at tag on question

Comment: @amit, for completeness just add note that it is 0 when n = 0

Comment: There's something that bugs me with this proof: Your choice of base is a bit arbitrary. Why did you pick *n* = 2? How does this come into play in the rest of the proof?

Comment: @aioobe The base is n=2,n=3 because it comes to play when later claiming `K(n)=K(n-1)*K(n-2)=0*0`. We assume `n>3`, otherwise the last equality is not guaranteed.

Comment: Is K(3) your base case?

Comment: @aioobe I have 2 bases here, since the recursion is using n-1, n-2. Similarly to the fact the fibonacci is defined for n=0,n=1 - because it recurses for both n-1,n-2. A general rule of thumb is if you recurse by n-1,n-2,...,n-i - you will need i base clauses.

Comment: What's making me feel uneasy about this proof is that you're missing argument 3.3 in my answer. As I see it you can't really use this approach without that step.

Comment: @aioobe I am not missing it, since I have two bases, my argument is **both** K(n-1)=0 AND K(n-2)=0. This claim is correct thanks to the double base I used. Your answer is perfectly fine as well, it just solves the issue in a different approach, you claim at least one is true, I claim both are true, and this is correct since for the step: `n>3 -> n-1>1, n-2>1`, and the claim holds.

Comment: I think I understand your argument, but your proof is pretty messy as it stands. You seem to do a case split between n < 2 and n >= 2. (I don't think it's necessary, but it probably works.) This causes some confusion because your first case is actually the base case of the recursive algorithm. Also, you put the "claim" part *after* you've proven the base case for that claim(?) This seems backward to me. Why not spell out the claim, then start proving the claim? Finally, I don't really understand the (1)... part (which is in fact the crucial part of the proof).

Answer (score 0):

Say `n = 0`. Since `0 < 2` we get `0` as result.

Say `n = 1`. Since `1 < 2` we get `1` as result.

Say `n = 2. K(2) = K(1)*K(0)`. Since `K(0) = 0` we get `0` as result.

For `n > 2` now we suppose that statement about algorithm is true, i.e. `K(n) = 0`.
Now let show that it is also true for `n + 1`:

`K(n + 1) = K(n)*K(n - 1)`. Since `K(n) = 0` it is obvious that `K(n)*K(n - 1) = 0`.